# SQL Error Log Message- 'ACCESS_METHODS_SCAN_RANGE_GENERATOR'

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

One of our SQL2005 Enterprise Servers running on Win2003 became unresponsive and on reboot I saw these errors logged before it went down.

---

Date        17/09/2009 10:16:22
Log     SQL Server (Archive #1 - 17/09/2009 10:17:00)

Source      spid111

Message
Timeout occurred while waiting for latch: class 'ACCESS_METHODS_SCAN_RANGE_GENERATOR', id 000000002A761760, type 4, Task 0x000000000E609EB8 : 14, waittime 600, flags 0x1a, owning task 0x000000000E6129B8. Continuing to wait.

---

Anyone know what this error points or relates to? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Also, around the same time it created a mini stack dump with a "Non-yielding Scheduler" message.

Comment: Does the log file show anything after that? Microsoft has *some* info at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175066.aspx.

Comment: Plus some more information here: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic647696-146-1.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the pointers Randolph, but we have been unable to either reproduce the problem or find the root cause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a cumulative update fix for the "Non-yielding Scheduler" condition.

Comment: Many Thanks jl, found the KB for the fix, it is available for:

SQL 2005: SP3 + CU6
SQL 2008: SP1 + CU5 or just CU8 if SP1 isn't applied

Comment: The fix is described in KB http://support.microsoft.com/kb/974205